# When should I invalidate an authentication token?

Tags: android

My app is using a custom Account Authenticator and sending data to Firebase.

From Android documentation:

> Auth tokens are normally reusable and cached by AccountManager, but must be refreshed periodically. It's the responsibility of applications to invalidate auth tokens when they stop working so the AccountManager knows it needs to regenerate them.

Still not clear for me. 
 1. Do they stop working from time to time? If so, why should I call `invalidateAuthToken()` ?

2. I am aware that I should not store users password. So I am sending it to Firebase and getting the AuthToken in return. But then, when I use `addAccountExplicitly`, what should I place into 'password' parameter?

Comment: When you make a request to Firebase that has the auth token as part of the request, does Firebase return some sort of response letting you know that the token has expired? If so, you would capture that response and invalidate the token in the AccountManager at that point.